# MVC route to a Angular app in a virtual folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an Angular running inside a MVC app. It is set up as a Virtual folder inside the Web application on the IIS.

Currently I have a IIS rewrite rule so the Routing is handled by the Angular app. But this is causing some other problems so I like to find out if it can be done with the MVC routing?

So everything at ../app/[pathandquery] should be routed to the app/[pathandquery] folder

Answer (score 0):

add this to webconfig

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thats what i have already. Was thinking if it could be done through MVC routing instead